# schedule backup and restore of SSAS 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

I can backup and restore databases on Microsoft SQL server Analysis Service 2008 using GUI as from [Backup SSAS](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Analysis+Services+(SSAS)/69469/)

I want to schedule backup and restore it to another server every night. so what i did is : I scripted out the backup and restore process from the GUI. Created a new SQL server agent job in database engine and added a "Run SSAS query" step. Copied the scripts to this step. But it fails.
the scripts that the GUI copied out look like:

```
<Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>DB</DatabaseID>
  </Object>
  <File>C:\Backup\DB.abf</File>
  <AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite>
</Backup>

<Restore xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <File>\\server\C$\Backup\DB.abf</File>
  <DatabaseName>DB</DatabaseName>
  <AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite>
</Restore>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed- 
the job step had to be "Run SSAS command" rather than "Run SSAS query"